# When $Hom_{\Lambda}(M,N)$ is a finitely generated $End_{\Lambda}(M)^{op}$-module?

Tags: modules, representation-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be a left artin ring. All modules and morphisms we consider are in $mod \Lambda$, the category of finitely generated left $\Lambda$-modules.  $M,N$ are two $\Lambda$-modules, then we know that $Hom_{\Lambda}(M,N)$ can also be seen as a $End_{\Lambda}(M)^{op}$-module.

Can we get that  $Hom_{\Lambda}(M,N)$ is a finitely generated $End_{\Lambda}(M)^{op}$-module? If not, under what conditions, can we get the result?